# Wordpress special register & login

Tags: wordpress

I have a question # wordpress
I was working on a Wordpress platform but after I finished growing my manager asked me to create a page where the visitor would sign up with two options:
Option 1: Register a company
Option 2: Register a normal member
How can I create a registration page so that the user chooses the type of registration and how can I assign specific permissions to each type?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use available Frontend Registration Forms Plugin. It will let you choose registration based on user roles too.

Comment: is there any plugin for this?

Comment: There is a lots of plugin available. Try Frontend User Pro